# Use jQuery without Script tag in head

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to make jQuery load inside my script. the user doesn't have to add the `<script>` to the head, but the script adds automatically. I tried using:

```
(function() {;
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = '/src/jquery-embed.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
      if (window.jQuery) {
        callback(jQuery);
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          checkReady(callback);
        }, 20);
      }
    };
    checkReady(function($) {
          //code here
          fucntion callbutton {
            console.log("i return as not defined when called by a button")
          }
```

when I add it, it works fine but all my functions break. How can I go about this without screwing up more?

edit: Link to the file im working on [here](https://git.nrrinc.net/Flyer/blob/broke/flyer/flyer.js)

Comment: Are you sure you are not just running into a dependency issue? If your other code, presumable loaded in `<script>` tags already in the `<head>` expects to use jQuery provided in this way, yes, all that code will break because jQuery might be the very _last_ thing getting loaded instead of the very _first_ that is necessary for all those other scripts to be able to use it.

Comment: dependency issue, exactly the issue. (couldnt think of what to call it). I need to load jquery before anything, how could i go about loading jquery from the script? (without making the user add a <script> tag)

Comment: You can't in practical terms that doesn't make it even more difficult for your users. The only way to achieve your goal would be to have the execution of every other script wait until your jQuery code executes. That will likely cause more confusion for your users than just asking them to include jQuery themselves.

Comment: i see what your saying, how could i go about loading jquery first before the other code runs? (im learning javascript, very bad at it)

Comment: The browser parses the HTML it receive from top to bottom sequentially. That means the `<script>` tags in the head are downloaded, read and executed by the browser immediately. That's why your code doesn't work, is because it is the last script to execute and is late to the party. So, every user script would have to wait for an event that your code publishes (we'll call it `doYourThing` event). So you would instruct your uses to create a handler (like they do for `document.ready`) for the `doYourThing` event.

Comment: Then, in your code above, after you append jQuery, you simply fire a [Custom Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) called `doYourThing`. If your users have followed your instructions, their code should run and execute just fine.

Comment: So i should append Jquery, then run my event?

Comment: That's the approach, yes.

Comment: I've provided some code for you to consider in a new answer. Please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: i added it to my code and it never loaded the event, I updated the github, could you see if i did anything wrong?

Comment: I added a link to a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SznndZ4mtwWj4BbB) that demonstrates the principle.

Comment: Ok so it got Jquery loaded, fine and dandy, but now i cant call the functions within it, how can i fix that?

Comment: Go to the plunkr and place any jQuery code you want to into the `userScript.js` file's `load()` function - they will work all day long. Your question has been answer, and I appreciate that you can't figure out how to adapt the _working model_ to you specific coding requirements. But this is pretty much as far as I go. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion, to achieve your goal you must ask your clients to delay their script execution until you've loaded your libraries (jQuery in this case).

Shown below is all that is necessary to accomplish the loading:

```
var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js';
script.onload = () => {
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('doYourThing'));
};
```

Then, your users would use this code:

```
    document.addEventListener('doYourThing', ()=>{
    // End user code that relies on jQuery goes here
    });
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SznndZ4mtwWj4BbB) that demonstrates the principle.

Comment: As I said in my comments, the end user must do something to make your magic work, either the code above, or adding a script tag. There is no benefit to the above solution given the content of your question.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot `document.body.appendChild()` and you also forgot to add the parentheses after `callbutton`
change it to this:

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.src = '/src/jquery-embed.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
      if (window.jQuery) {
        callback(jQuery);
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          checkReady(callback);
        }, 20);
      }
    };
    checkReady(function($) {
          //code here
          function callbutton(){
            console.log("i return as not defined when called by a button")
          }
    }
  })
```

Comment: I got the Following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"
here is what im working on: https://git.nrrinc.net/Flyer/blob/broke/flyer/flyer.js

Comment: That's because I wasn't using an editor for typing the javascript. Try typing it in without copy and paste.